# "I" Operator except non integral and not bool types

Tags: c#, operators

I'm trying to understand, where to use `|` Operator. On [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx) there is told that

> Binary | operators are predefined for the integral types and bool.

and

> User-defined types can overload the `|` operator

So, when I see something like :
 `BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.ExactBinding`
or

```
 NotifyFilters.Attributes | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastAccess
```

I assume that this is overloaded `|`  operator and logic will be like :  somthing or something else or etc. But how can I indicate that operator `|` is defined for some class?

Comment: Do you know want to define the operator or do you want to find out whether it is defined for a type?

Comment: When I see `NotifyFilters.Attributes | NotifyFilters.FileName` I assume `NotifyFilters` is an enum not a class. That's true for `BindingFlags` too.

Comment: dcastro - I want to find out whether it is defined for a type.
Sriram Sakthivel -  yes, they are enums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, these are `enum`s that are represented internally as an `int`. (You could cast these `enum`s to an `int` without any problems and vice versa.) Such `int`s/`enums` are called flags. In other langugages like C there is no extra `enum` type, so they are just plain `int`s or other integer types.

So it's still the case as stated in your first quote:

> Binary | operators are predefined for the integral types and bool.

To your other question

> But how can I indicate that operator | is defined for some class?

Operators are overloaded using the `operator` keyword. Note: not every operator is overloadable, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx).

```
// example addition operator from a complex number class
public static Complex operator +(Complex c1, Complex c2)
{
    Return new Complex(c1.real + c2.real, c1.imaginary + c2.imaginary);
}
```

You can use [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) to determine at runtime whether a class implements a certain operator. Internally, operators are just methods. For example, the `==` operator is implemented in the method `op_Equality`. So, if such a method exists, the `==` operator is available. (You only can see those methods with reflection, they are not callable in normal C# code). [See](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/8zz808e6(v=vs.110).aspx) `GetMethod()` from the Reflection API how to determine the existence of an operator.

Code example for the `+` operator

```
MethodInfo operator = typeof(YourClass).GetMethod("op_Addition");

if (operator != null) // if null the operator is not implemented
   operator.Invoke(null, firstInstance, secondInstance);
```

I don't know what the method name for the `|` operator is, but you can easily check that with a decompiler tool. It should be something like `op_BinaryOr`.

If you just want to know if you can use an operator in your code, this should be provided by your IDE, Visual Studio for example shows operators in the IntelliSense autocomplete list or the Object Browser.

Answer (score 1):

It means, that the enum-values are "combined" with the `or`-operator. Imagine the following:

```
public enum MY_ENUM
    : int
{
    FOO = 1,
    BAR = 2,
    TEST = 4,
    ALL_VALUES = 7,
}
```

The value `FOO | BAR | TEST` would be equal to `ALL_VALUES`, as the following calculation shows:

```
result := FOO | BAR | TEST
        =  1  |  2  |  4    // <-- this is a normal OR-operation
        = 7

  --> result == ALL_VALUES
```

**Conclusion:** All values of an enum are processed like "normal" integer numbers and can be used with any binary or math operator.

---

[See this msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664601(v=vs.71).aspx)

---

**EDIT:** You can also use the [`[Flags]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)-Attribute on your Enum, if you want a better output of your binary operations on Enum variables.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is not much point in doing this, but you definitely can override the | operator:

```
public static MyClass operator |(MyClass left, MyClass right)
{
    //your logic here
}
```

Basically what that operator does, is that it combines the hex values of two integers like this:

```
int a = 0x0402;  //1026
int b = 0x5030;  //20528
int c = a | b;   //21554 (same as a+b)
string hex = "0x"+ c.ToString("X4"); //0x5432
```

But don't confuse it with the + operator

```
int a = 0x0007;  //7
int b = 0x000B;  //11
int c = a | b;   //15 (a+b would be 0x0012)
string hex = "0x"+ c.ToString("X4"); //0x000F
```

For enums the underlying value is what gets | -d

Here is an example

```
        [Flags]
        enum ActionFlags : int
        {
            DoThis = 0x00000001,
            DoThat = 0x00000010,
            DoOtherThing = 0x00000100,
            DoAnotherThing = 0x00001000,
            MaxValue = 0x00001111,
            MinValue = 0x00000000,
        }

        void DoStuff(ActionFlags what_to_do)
        {
            if ((int)(what_to_do) > (int)(ActionFlags.MaxValue) || 
                (int)(what_to_do) < (int)(ActionFlags.MinValue))
                throw new ArgumentException();
            if(what_to_do.HasFlag(ActionFlags.DoThis))
            {
                // do this
            }
            if (what_to_do.HasFlag(ActionFlags.DoThat))
            {
                // do that
            }
            if (what_to_do.HasFlag(ActionFlags.DoOtherThing))
            {
                // do other thing
            }
            if (what_to_do.HasFlag(ActionFlags.DoAnotherThing))
            {
                // do another thing
            }
        }
```

```
DoStuff(ActionFlags.DoThat | ActionFlags.DoOtherThing);
```

The reason why you should't bother making your own | , is that like msdn says, it's already predefined for all numeric types, and for most other classes this sort of binary logic is unnecessary.